# WebApi 2 Route Attribute not working unless using parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a controller List

```
[Route("api/cache/list")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> List()
{
   ...
}
```

But i get a 404 if i try to go to localhost:12121/api/cache/list. My webapi config looks like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            //);
        }
    }
```

On the other hand if i change that controller to

```
[Route("api/cache/list/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> List(int id =0)
{
   ...
}
```

It will work. Ive tried doing it without the id as a parameter, still doenst work. What am I doing wrong here?

**Extra Info:**

I do have a strange setup. My WebApiConfig.cs and global.cs are in a different project. The project which has my controller will then reference the project with the WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Not sure if its possible to invoke the method without the id param

Comment: It's optional but may not be negligible

Comment: well if you take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes You can see that they use a route for books that has no id in it.

Comment: Also i would be willing to add the /{id} but then when i go to that url it requires an id or it returns 404

Comment: In that case remove param from your get

Comment: I did, still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving the param a default value, try making your id param nullable:

```
public IEnumerable<string> List(int? id)
```

Then check for null in code.  This also helps differentiate a passed zero from an omitted param value.

Comment: Did you specify the parameter is optional in your route definition?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Comment: It wasnt before, but now it is. It currently looks like this `[Route("api/cache/list/{id:int?}")]` , but still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to figure out how to fix the problem exactly but I did find a way around my problem.

First  I correctly identified that when my routing was in a single assembly the exact same code worked fine. When the routing for my project in a different assembly makes it difficult for `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to correctly identify attribute routes.

On the other hand using a `RoutePrefix` seemed to fix my issue.

Im not going to set this as my answer because I feel it doesn't truly address the problem, but I felt it would be informational to anyone who comes along this question.